# Storing a integer as a 32 bit value in char array across 4 bytes

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, riscv

I have a quick question

I have this function here, that stores an integer across 4 bytes as hexadecimal characters

```
    void store_int(unsigned char* arr, int index, int value) {
    arr[index] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+3] = value & 0xFF;
}
```

Now, I am working on a function called store, that stores an integer across 32 bits, I would just like some confirmation

Is this method okay,

I input the integer using this method at index 0,  which stores the index across 0,1,2,3

Then I call the read_int method, below which reads the index from 0 to position, the input is the same as my output, but I just want to make sure it is actually storing it in 32 bit(not too fussed about endianness)

```
    int read_int(const unsigned char* arr, int index) {
    int value = 0;
    value |= ((int)arr[index]) << 24;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+1]) << 16;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+2]) << 8;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+3]);
    return value;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: The only potential issue I can see is for negative numbers, the 24-bit left-shift will overflow.  It might be safest to construct an `unsigned int` value using `unsigned` shifts, then cast the final result to `int`.

Comment: Always consider endian-ness.  You can flip everything if needed.  And you're not saving them as hexadecimal "characters."  Just groups of eight bits.  Just happens that `unsigned char` is exactly 8 bits on your machine.  But to your question, `int` on your machine/target/build settings might or might not be 32 bits.

Comment: @TomKarzes

A thousand apologies, if you are not too busy, do you mind demonstrating it, I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Should I be using uint_32 in that case?

Answer (score 1):

> but I just want to make sure it is actually storing it in 32 bit(not
> too fussed about endianness)

If not then the safest and easiest way is to :

```
void *store_int(void *arr, size_t index, int value)
{
    unsigned char *ucarr = arr;
    memcpy(ucarr + index, &value, sizeof(value));
    return ucarr;
}

int read_int(const void *arr, size_t index) 
{
    int value;
    const unsigned char *ucarr = arr;
    memcpy(&value, ucarr + index, sizeof(value));
    return value;
}
```

Your code is implementation-defined as right shift of signed integer is implementation defined. It is better to use unsigned numbers

```
void *store_int(void *arr, size_t index, int value) {
    unsigned int uvalue = (unsigned)value;
    unsigned char *ucb = arr;
    ucb[index] = (uvalue >> 24) & 0xFF;
    ucb[index+1] = (uvalue >> 16) & 0xFF;
    ucb[index+2] = (uvalue >> 8) & 0xFF;
    ucb[index+3] = uvalue & 0xFF;
    return ucb + index;
}

int read_int(const void *arr, size_t index) {
    unsigned value = 0;
    const unsigned char *ucb = arr;
    value |= (unsigned)ucb[index] << 24;
    value |= (unsigned)ucb[index+1] << 16;
    value |= (unsigned)ucb[index+2] << 8;
    value |= (unsigned)ucb[index+3];
    return (int)value;
}
```

Comment: How can I preserve sign with unsigned numbers tho?

Comment: @HyperCoderSuperion They will have the same binary representation. Do not worry - it is well defined in C standard.

Comment: @HyperCoderSuperion https://godbolt.org/z/nv8xo4Pnd